# how to make a submit button redirect to another website when submiting?

Tags: submit

I have a HTML page. I have a submit button on the page. When user clicks the button, I want to redirect him to another site. Where should I put the code? Please be specific.
Thanks for advance !

Comment: do you want the user to submit form data, then redirect, or just click and redirect or redirect on error or ...?

Comment: just click and redirect

Comment: they're called hyperlinks not forms

Comment: Exactly, how do i add one to my button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
<form action="http://myRedirectedSite.com/redirectedPage.html" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You could use either get or post as the method depending on the other site. Note that any form field values will be passed to the other site.

Comment: my html code is this :                                           <html>
  <body>
    <form action="http://www.fiverr.com/users/doitthis" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">   ...........                                                                                                             <input type="submit" value="See The Picture" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>